# Paginate items in collections

Tags: plone

I'm using the new collections implementation that was introduced with Plone 4.2. The problem is that pages are not paginated. In the edition form there is a field to put a number of items to be showed, but it is ignored.

In the buildout I'm using this:

http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2/versions.cfg

I remember that pagination works in the old collections. How can I paginate using the new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you found a bug, I can confirm that "Limit Search Results" is ignored, would you mind to report it?

You could use the old-style-collections still in P42 by enabling them in the types-controlpanel, but they are deprecated and porting old-style to new-style is not supported either, afaik.